# Where is GetTickCount declared in Firemonkey?

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

I am using multi device in Delphi and I am building an android app. I need to use `GetTickCount` that was declared in Windows .

Does it exist somewhere in firemonkey or is there an alternative ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`GetTickCount` is a Windows function and so does not exist on other platforms. For your cross platform needs you should use [`TStopWatch`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Diagnostics.TStopwatch) from `System.Diagnostics`.

Answer (score 14):

use [TThread.GetTickCount](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Classes.TThread.GetTickCount) it's cross platform

Comment: This suffers from roll over due to return type being 32 bit

Comment: This is better answer, anyway.

Comment: Good answer, but the resolution of `GetTickCount` sucks. It is artificially limited to 1 MS resolution. [On Windows it has a drift of +/- 10 to 16](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724408%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) milliseconds. Much better to use TStopWatch. And (as per david's comment) every 47.6 days your timer will roll over.

Comment: Bringing <insert your fave RTC facility> as portable alternative to GetTickCount is such a nonsense!

Comment: @FreeConsulting What is so bad about TStopWatch? Is it the answer you don't approve of, or the answerer?

Comment: Is TThread.GetTickCount any worse than the Windows API function? As far as I can see it suffers the same shortcomings but nothing worse.

Comment: @dummzeuch not worse no, just the same pitfalls